# What do the WMI classes mean by "speed of memory, in nanoseconds"?

Tags: windows, winapi, wmi

So, for one reason or another, I'm trawling through WMI class documentation trying to make sense of what a few things mean.

One of the most confusing things I've found so far is [CIM_PhysicalMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387968(v=vs.85).aspx). It has the property "Speed" which it says means:

> Speed of the physical memory, in nanoseconds.

What does that mean? How would you measure this?

Comment: Refers to the minimum amount of time for the memory to be refreshed. Its a bit of a misnomer to refer to it purely as memory "speed", because it technically refers to a maximum rate of refresh the memory can support. The "real world" speed is constrained by the host bus architecture/components.

Comment: It is not measured, the BIOS knows about it since it initializes the memory controller.  Usually it means the RAS time, details are here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_random-access_memory#Memory_timing